# ¿Se puede realizar boton escuchar voz sin el diseño de la api de google?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-api

Tengo una aplicación que mediante el clic de un `Button` utiliza la api de **Google** para captar la voz e interpretar las palabras que dice,
sin embargo me gustaría realizar la misma acción pero sin que aparezca la interfaz escucha de **Google** ya que no va con el diseño de mi aplicación.

Que sea con un diseño similar al de mi aplicación o que no aparezca necesariamente el boton de **Google**  de escuchando.

**Algo parecido a lo que realiza Duolingo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente con la **api** de **Google**  ya capto la voz e interpreto las palabras que dice el usuario con el siguiente codigo

```
public void btnSpeak(View v) {
    Intent intentActionRecognizeSpeech = new Intent(
            RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intentActionRecognizeSpeech.putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "es-MX");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intentActionRecognizeSpeech,
                RECOGNIZE_SPEECH_ACTIVITY);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
       ;
    }
}
```

El problema es que al realizar eso muestra el boton de **Google** escuchando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso de realizar el intent con la constante [Recognizer.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent) se inicia una actividad que solicitará al usuario la voz y la enviará a través de un reconocedor de voz del dispositivo, en este caso el de Google.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Por lo tanto si deseas agregar  dentro de tu aplicación el reconocedor de voz necesitaras otra opción que no se realice a travez de un intent.**

La aplicación que comentas usa su propia API, por lo tanto tendrías que buscar otra opción.

Te recomiendo revisar:

https://cmusphinx.github.io/

https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/